# Selenium: google search results in Spanish within a time window

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to refine the code to scrape some results on Google using Selenium.  I am looking for selecting results in a specific language (Spanish), within a time window.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('apple pie')
search.submit()
```

but I would need to filter only *results in Spanish* between a start date and an end date.

How could I do to refine it?

Comment: what do you mean by  not filter the page based on language in a date range window

Comment: I would like to filter only results in a specified language (Spanish) between start_date and end_date

Comment: sounds like regex

Comment: I would need to select the results since the beginning, when I search 'apple pie' (like in advanced search). If I change in `www.google.es`, it does not return only Spanish results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Change the browser preference/option languages in your script*

*Example*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


def example():
    fire_fox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fire_fox_profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'es-mx, es')
    firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe',
                                        firefox_profile=fire_fox_profile)

    firefox_browser.get('https://www.google.es/')
    time.sleep(3)  # wait page to load 3 sec
    search = firefox_browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys('apple pie')
    search.submit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    example()
```

*https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities*

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'es'})
chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome_browser.get('https://www.google.es/')
time.sleep(2)  # wait page to load 3 sec
search = chrome_browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('apple pie')
search.submit()
```

*[How to set browser locale with chromedriver (Python)](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/32459)*

Comment: Thank you 0m3r. I tried with the second as I am using Chrome. However,setting Spanish, (es, es_ES) as preferences, I find also English results. Also with Italian or Deutsch I find English results. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think the problem is that your code changes Chrome language, but what I would like are only Spanish results (so Spanish as languages and Spain as country)

Comment: I don't have Chrome but let me double check on the correct string @Val

Comment: @0mr3r :Would you know also how to set a date range? (e.g. between 20 March 2020 and 22 March 2020)